# Google Scripts onEdit to trigger another function upon selection change in drop down menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

I have a working function set up which searches another tab for a match from the selection in a drop down menu, and then copies the background/font colours from a specified grid below the match and pastes it onto a grid in the main tab. The script is as follows:

```
    function cellColours() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheetRanges = ss.getSheets()[2]
    var sheetCalculator = ss.getSheets()[0]

    var dropdownMenu = sheetCalculator.getRange("F2")
    var dropdownValue = dropdownMenu.getValue()
    var textFinder = sheetRanges.createTextFinder(dropdownValue)
    var firstOccurrence = textFinder.findNext()

    var startCell = firstOccurrence.offset(2, 0)
    var endCell = startCell.offset(12, 12)

    var rangesGrid = 
    sheetRanges.getRange(startCell.getA1Notation()+':'+endCell.getA1Notation())
    var cellColours = rangesGrid.getBackgrounds()
    var textColours = rangesGrid.getFontColorObjects()

    var calculatorGrid = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("F4:R16")
    var cellColourPaste = calculatorGrid.setBackgrounds(cellColours)
    var textColourPaste = calculatorGrid.setFontColorObjects(textColours)
    }
```

What I would like to happen is for the script to be automatically run whenever the selection in the dropdown menu (cell F2) is changed - have been messing around with onEdit to no avail! Is there a way for telling the on edit to run a different script when this menu is changed?

I have also tried incorporating the function into onEdit like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var range = e.range;
var spreadsheet = e.source;
var sheetName = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
var column = range.getcolumn();
var row = range.getrow();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheetRanges = ss.getSheets()[2]
var sheetCalculator = ss.getSheets()[0]

var dropdownMenu = sheetCalculator.getRange("F2")
var dropdownValue = dropdownMenu.getValue()
var textFinder = sheetRanges.createTextFinder(dropdownValue)
var firstOccurrence = textFinder.findNext()

var startCell = firstOccurrence.offset(2, 0)
var endCell = startCell.offset(12, 12)

var rangesGrid = sheetRanges.getRange(startCell.getA1Notation()+':'+endCell.getA1Notation())

if(sheetName == 'Calculator' && column == 6 && row == 2)
{SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Shoving 
Ranges').getRange(rangesGrid).getBackgrounds()
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Shoving 
Ranges').getRange(rangesGrid).getFontColorObjects()
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Calculator').getRange("F4:R16") 
 .setBackgrounds().setFontColorObjects()
 }
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm very new to scripting and while banging my head against the wall until I find something that works has got me this far I'm afraid I've run out of surfaces to slap for this last part!

Thanks
Feargus

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is evaluate e before doing the rest of the work. Set your `onEdit` function to the following, which confirms if the cell that was edited is the dropdown menu and then, if it was, runs the `cellColours()` function.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetCalculator = ss.getSheets()[0]
  var dropdownMenu = sheetCalculator.getRange("F2").getA1Notation
  
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation;
  if (cell = dropdownMenu) {
    cellColours();
  }
}
```

Also, I noticed the last two lines of your original function declare variables but you can just call the methods unless you need to use:

```
    calculatorGrid.setBackgrounds(cellColours)
    calculatorGrid.setFontColorObjects(textColours)
```

Comment: You absolute legend!! Thanks a mill!!

Comment: Glad it helps! Here's how to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).